# JPA primary key value is always 0

Tags: java, jpa, primary-key, playframework

I have a post class and it kind of works, but there's one problem: the primary key doesn't increase.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="posts")
public class Post extends GenericModel{

    @Id
    @Column(name="post_id")
    public int id;

    @Column(name="post_situation")
    public String situation;

    @Column(name="post_date")
    public Date date;

    @Column(name="post_userid")
    public int userid;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="post", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    public List<Block> blocks;

    public Post addBlock(String content, int position){
        Block b = new Block(this, content, position);
        b.save();

        this.blocks.add(b);

        this.save();
        return this;
    }

    public Post(String situation, Date date){
        this.situation = situation;
        this.date = date;
        this.userid = 2;
    }

}
```

When I call it the first time on an empty table, it works fine, but the second time, I'm getting `PersistenceException occured : org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Could not execute JDBC batch update`
The post_id column always has 0. Any idea how to fix this? I have the @Id annotation in palce..

This is how I have in my controller:

```
    Post p = new Post("Midden in het middenoosten.", new Date()).save();
```

Any ideas what's causing this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you want the primary key values to be auto-generated. If that is the case, if you'll need to add the `@GeneratedValue` annotation to the `id` attribute, in addition to the `@Id` annotation. Your code should therefore be:

```
@Id
@Column(name="post_id")
@GeneratedValue
public int id;
```

[There are several strategies](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Identity_and_Sequencing#Sequence_Strategies) available to generate the Ids. You would have to read up on those to decide if you want to choose the `TABLE` -based, `SEQUENCE` -based or the `IDENTITY` -based strategy (which depends on what your database supports). If you choose a strategy explicitly, the define strategy will be used, instead of the default AUTO strategy. Explicit strategy decisions, are communicated in code as:

```
@Id
@Column(name="post_id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=SEQUENCE, generator="POST_SEQ")
public int id;
```

Without generated values, the default value for integers in Java, i.e. 0 will be persisted for the `post_id` column. Due to the primary key constraint, you cannot have a second row with the same key, resulting in the described failure.

Comment: Shouldn't mysql be able to generate the primary key itself, when it's left open in the query? Is there maybe a way to make JPA ignore it when saving an object, and only use it for reading?

Comment: I hadn't read your updated answer. i tried without the @GeneratedValue parameters, and now it's telling me `java.sql.SQLException: Field 'post_id' doesn't have a default value`

Comment: Yes,my SQL can do that as well. You need to specify for that column  while creating table.

Comment: Are you referring to AUTO_INCREMENT columns? If so, you'll need to choose the IDENTITY strategy.

Comment: Deleting the table and having JPA regenerate it again after @GeneratedValue was added to the code, fixed the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Sled, you're welcome. I would like to point out that the AUTO strategy usually results in the TABLE strategy being chosen, so you're better of specifying the one that you need.

Comment: I'll have a better look at the different strategies and try to specify the right one

Answer (score 1):

There are several strategies available to generate id:

1. `GenerationType.AUTO`
2. `GenerationType.SEQUENCE`
3. `GenerationType.IDENTITY`
4. `GenerationType.TABLE`

If you want the primary key values to be auto-generated, use `GenerationType.AUTO`, it works with MySQL.